# How to store 'yield' generator result in a list in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, format

I have a code like this:

```
import math    
nList = [[[0, 0, 0], [3, 2, 1]],\
     [[]],\
     [[1, 1, 12]],\
     [[0, 0, 0], [30000, 40, 3010], [32000, 40500, 7520], [0, 0, 10520]],\
     [[15340, 0, 0], [104300, 0, 3630], [434000, 4434000, 63460]]]

def calculate_length(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

def calculate_time (t1,t2):
    return abs(t1-t2)

def lengths(trace):
    previous_x, previous_y = 0, 0
    for index, point in enumerate(trace):
        if point:
            x, y, t = point
            if index > 0:
                yield calculate_length(x, y, previous_x, previous_y)
            previous_x, previous_y = x, y
```

How would I store the `yield` results of `calculate_length(x, y, previous_x, previous_y)` in a list?

`nList` has `traces` in them with each `trace` having `points` with 3 elements, `[x,y,t]`. I need to store the lengths of each trace so that the output generated is:

```
all_lengths_list=[[3]],[[]],[[]],[[30000.02667],[40509.40138],[51616.37337]],[[88960],[4446240]]]
```

Comment: `all_lengths_list = [length for length in lengths(nList)]` would work (assuming `nList` is defined properly). You don't need those `\\` characters at the end of lines in it, btw.

Comment: @martineau: No, because there are multiple traces, each containing (possibly) multiple points in `nList`. So `all_lengths_list = [[v for v in lengths(tr)] for tr in nList]`, would work, but I think `all_lengths_list = [list(lengths(tr)) for tr in nList]` is more succinct.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Yes, you appear to be right.

Comment: I've added the missing brackets for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need those line-continuation backslashes - modern Python is smart enough to figure out that the list definition isn't complete and so it does the line-continuation automatically for you.

Also, there's no need to import the math module just to calculate a square root, you can use the built-in power operator: `** 0.5`.

To get the output you want you need to feed the trace lists in `nList` to your generator one at a time, capturing the resulting data into lists which are then saved in `all_lengths_list`. This can be done in a normal for loop, but it's more compact to use a list comprehension, as in the code below. To display the contents of `all_lengths_list` I use `pprint()` from the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module. It's not *that* pretty, but it's better than putting it all onto one line. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pprint import pprint

nList = [
    [[0, 0, 0], [3, 2, 1]],
    [[]],
    [[1, 1, 12]],
    [[0, 0, 0], [30000, 40, 3010], [32000, 40500, 7520], [0, 0, 10520]],
    [[15340, 0, 0], [104300, 0, 3630], [434000, 4434000, 63460]]
]

def calculate_length(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2) ** 0.5

def calculate_time (t1,t2):
    return abs(t1-t2)

def lengths(trace):
    previous_x, previous_y = 0, 0
    for index, point in enumerate(trace):
        if point:
            x, y, t = point
            if index > 0:
                yield calculate_length(x, y, previous_x, previous_y)
            previous_x, previous_y = x, y

all_lengths_list = [list(lengths(trace)) for trace in nList]

pprint(all_lengths_list, indent=4)
```

**output**

```
[   [3.6055512754639891],
    [],
    [],
    [30000.026666654816, 40509.401377951763, 51616.373371247231],
    [88960.0, 4446240.8942836197]]
```

Comment: @sayna: My pleasure! If you like it, please feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. However, I'm not sure why you have the `if index > 0:` test. But it's your algorithm. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring i just answered to get yield value.You gone  through its algorithm.Good work.OP didnt upvote.But i do. :)

Comment: @itzmeontv; Thanks. I guess my point is that sayna was a bit confused by your & Daniel's answers, since he thought he could apply them directly.

Comment: Hi @itzmeontv. Thanks for all your help as well! Sorry, I wish I could upvote at that time but I didn't have enough reputation yet to do so! :P

Answer (score 4):

Just use `list`:

```
result = list(lengths(trace))
```

Comment: I get the error NameError: name 'trace' is not defined if I try that. Thanks for your answer though @Daniel.

Comment: @sayna, you cannot just copy and paste without any thinking... `trace` is only an argument for whatever you call the function with, in your case `trace` is `nList`.

Comment: I apologise @Anzel. I'm very new to programming.

Comment: @sayna, no need to apologise. This is the spirit of SO, everyone here is trying to help but you do need to put your own effort to tackle the problem itself. We love helping others who has tried really hard but cannot solve the problem.

Comment: @Anzel: No, `trace` isn't `nList`: `nList` contains multiple `trace`s, so we have to iterate over `nList`, processing each `trace`.

Answer (score 1):

you can get `yield` by

```
l = lengths(nList)
next(l) # gives 1st yield
next(l) # gives 2nd
```

and so on

To get all in a list

```
>>>list(lengths(nList))
```

Comment: I get the error     "list(lengths(arg))
NameError: global name 'arg' is not defined" if I try that. Thanks though @itzmeontv.

Comment: `arg` is just any argument to function.i think you are passing list.So try `list(lengths(nList))`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, now my main code is showing an error of  line 15, in lengths
    x, y, t = point
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

Comment: what is the indention for that line ? i mean what you are expecting from it

Comment: that the lists within lists, like [0,0,0] and [3,2,1] with [x,y,t] variables are in points. Basically nList[index]=trace and trace[index]=point with point=[x,y,t].

Comment: t is not using anywhere ?

Comment: Sorry @itzmeontv, this isn't going to work. See my answer & various comments.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `nList` in your code isn't complete and needs a couple of closing `]` brackets to be syntactically correct. Also, once a definition of something has been started with an opening `(` or `[` it's not necessary to explicitly add line-continuation `\` backslash characters if it is then spread across several subsequent lines. This makes them easier to write and a lot cleaner and more natural looking.

With that correction, you could store the values `yield`ed from the `lengths()` function in a `list` like something like this:

```
all_lengths_list = [[length for length in lengths(trace)] for trace in nList]
```

or more even more concisely, like so:

```
all_lengths_list = list((list(lengths(trace)) for trace in nList))
```

I would also like to mention a few things that you could do simplify and optimize your code. Besides `sqrt()`, the built-in `math` module also has a `hypot()` function which make it easy to calculate distance as your `calculate_length()` function is doing and will speed it up since more of the mathematical operations will be done in the module's C code instead of Python.

Another thing I noticed was that your `lengths()` function seems overly complicated and could be greatly streamlined by using some of Python's more advanced features. For starters, why not just have it return the list of points itself, rather than yielding the pieces of one, one-at-a-time.

Beyond that, Python's `iterools` module contains a number of functions and recipes based on them that make it easy to do iterative things, like calculations. In particular there's one recipe for a generator function called [`pairwise()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise#recipes) which yields the elements of a sequence in tuples, or pairs, of two — which makes it extremely useful for calculating distances as is being done in `lengths()`.

Below is a modified version of your code incorporating all of the above corrections and suggestions. I also added some stuff at the end to display the results in a fairly readable format.

```
import itertools
import math

nList = [[[0, 0, 0], [3, 2, 1]],
         [[]],
         [[1, 1, 12]],
         [[0, 0, 0], [30000, 40, 3010], [32000, 40500, 7520], [0, 0, 10520]],
         [[15340, 0, 0], [104300, 0, 3630], [434000, 4434000, 63460]]]

def calculate_length(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.hypot(x1-x2, y1-y2)

def calculate_time (t1,t2):
    return abs(t1-t2)

def pairwise(iterable):  # see http://preview.tinyurl.com/mzbfqlt
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

def lengths(trace):
    return [calculate_length(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                for (x1, y1, t1), (x2, y2, t2) in pairwise(trace)]

all_lengths_list = list(lengths(trace) for trace in nList)

for pts_list, length_list in zip(nList, all_lengths_list):
    print('   points: {}\n'
          'distances: [{}]'.format(
              pts_list,
              ', '.join((format(length, '.2f') for length in length_list))))
```

Output:

```
   points: [[0, 0, 0], [3, 2, 1]]
distances: [3.61]
   points: [[]]
distances: []
   points: [[1, 1, 12]]
distances: []
   points: [[0, 0, 0], [30000, 40, 3010], [32000, 40500, 7520], [0, 0, 10520]]
distances: [30000.03, 40509.40, 51616.37]
   points: [[15340, 0, 0], [104300, 0, 3630], [434000, 4434000, 63460]]
distances: [88960.00, 4446240.89]
```